# event.target of a jQuery click event returning the child of the clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, jquery-events

I have a jQuery click event on a hyperlink containing an image. Both the hyperlink and the image has seperate `id`s. I'd expect that when I click the hyperlink, the code `event.target.id` inside the event handler would return the hyperlink `id` as the event is tied to the hyperlink, but it returns the image `id`. Why is that? Is there any way to always make the element tied to the event become the `event.target`?

HTML:

```
<div id="menuContainer">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a id="home"><img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a></li>
        <li><a id="about">Om oss</a></li>
        <li><a id="concept">Konsept</a></li>
        <li><a id="history">Data</a></li>
        <li><a id="store">Butikk</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="frontpage"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

JS:

```
function Page(pageId, linkId, file, backgroundImg, showPage){
    this.id = pageId;
    this.link = linkId;
    this.content = file;
    this.img = backgroundImg;
    this.show = showPage;

    this.loadPage = function() {
        if (this.show && $cont.is(":hidden")) $cont.show();
        else if (!this.show && $cont.is(":visible")) $cont.hide();
        if (this.content != "") $cont.load(this.content);
        else $cont.html("");
        $("#frontpage").css("backgroundImage", "url(img/" + this.img + ")");
    }
}

var pages = [];
var linkToPageId = {};

function addPage(linkId, file, backgroundImg, showPage = true) {
    var pageId = pages.length;
    var newPage = new Page(pageId, linkId, file, backgroundImg, showPage);
    pages.push(newPage);
    linkToPageId[linkId] = pageId;
}

addPage("home", "", "frontpage.jpg", false);

$("#menu a").click(function(event){
    console.log(event.target.id);
    pages[linkToPageId[event.target.id]].loadPage();
});
```

PS. I know this can be quickfixed by giving changing the `linkId` of this specific `Page` object to "logo" instead of "home", but it kinda spaghettifies the code. I would like to see if there's any other option first.

PSS. I also know JS has actual `Class`es instead of the function-based "class" I've used. It's irrelevant to my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `event.target` will always be the element that *dispatched* the event. If you click on an element inside a container, then no matter what element the listener is attached to, the `event.target` will be the element inside the container.

If you want a reference to the element the listener is attached to, use `this` or `event.currentTarget`:

```js
$("#menu a").click(function() {
  console.log(this.id);
  // pages[linkToPageId[this.id]].loadPage();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menuContainer">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li>
      <a id="home"><img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="about">Om oss</a></li>
    <li><a id="concept">Konsept</a></li>
    <li><a id="history">Data</a></li>
    <li><a id="store">Butikk</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="frontpage"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

```js
$("#menu a").click(function() {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.id);
  // pages[linkToPageId[event.currentTarget]].loadPage();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menuContainer">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li>
      <a id="home"><img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="about">Om oss</a></li>
    <li><a id="concept">Konsept</a></li>
    <li><a id="history">Data</a></li>
    <li><a id="store">Butikk</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="frontpage"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you use `event.currentTarget` which points to the element that you attached the listener. It does not change as the event bubbles.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Your wording is misleading. Actually `Event.currentTarget` does change when bubbling, `Event.target` does not since it always points to the dispatcher.

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSS tricks that will ignore hover and click events for the element on which is set the rule:

```css
#menu a img {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This rule will cancel your `:hover` rules on that element (and children because of the cascading beauty of CSS).

```js
document
    .querySelectorAll("#menu a")
    .forEach(
        (element) => element.addEventListener(
            "click", 
            (event) => document.querySelector("#click-target").textContent = event.target.outerHTML
        )
    );
```

```css
#menu a span.icon {
    pointer-events: none;
}
#menu a span:hover {
    color: #F0F;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<p>Try me by clicking on links or on the "checkbox" icons.</p>

<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#"><span class="icon">☑ </span> pointer-events: none</a>
  <li><a href="#"><span>☐ </span> No pointer-events rule</a>
</ul>

<div id="click-target"></div>
```